# Yii - protected - (403 Forbidden Error)

Tags: sqlite, post, yii, http-status-code-403, protected

Is it possible to change the configuration of Yii, to:

1- make Yii and the database accessible from outside the folder 'protected'

2- send data from outside the folder 'protected' to files inside 'protected'

Or is there any other solution to do this ?

thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible since the protected folder is only protected by a .htaccess file.
If you eliminate the "defensive rules" and have the right directory/file permissions, the protected folder can be easily made accessible from outside.

However I strongly recommend not to do this, because direct access to the protected folder (as it name suggests) should be made inaccessible for standard users.

Comment: Yes it is not recommended, but since I did not do it before, I still need help and want to know if someone has experience with it and can show me how to do it.

Comment: You only need to edit (well, clear) the `.htaccess` file in the `protected` folder to achieve that and grant the necessary permissions on the filesystem.